# VBA Excel: Compile Error: Object required?

Tags: excel, vba

I get a VBA Excel 'Compiler Error: Object required'-Error in the marked line.
I do not understand the reason.

BTW: Wish Excel would support a .Net language without wrapper needs.

```
Option Explicit

Public Type Inherit
    ReqId As Integer
    Parent As Integer
    Depth As Integer
    Path As String
End Type

Sub test()
    Dim MyStructure() As Inherit
    ReDim MyStructure(1 To 1000)

    MyStructure(1).ReqId = 1

    Dim Data, refData As Inherit
    Set Data = MyStructure(1)  ' <---! 
    Beep

End Sub
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Set` is for the assignment of objects, a user defined type is treated like a regular variable so use `=` to assign.

Also (confusingly); `Dim Data, refData As Inherit` only declares `refData` of type `Inherit` to declare them both on one line you must; `Dim Data As Inherit, refData As Inherit`

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim Data, refData As Inherit
```

declares `Data` as `Variant`, only `refData` as `Inherit`.

```
Dim Data As Inherit, refData As Inherit
```

does what you want. The VBA syntax is not "common sense" here, I have seen this error dozens of times. EDIT: of course, you will have to leave out `Set` in the assignment, since `Inherit` is a user defined type.

If you are looking for a free and easy to use .NET integration for Excel, look at Excel-DNA:

http://exceldna.codeplex.com/