# VBA Excel "Compile error: Object Required"

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on VBA code in excel and i have the following piece of code

```
Set strModel = Right(rng.Offset(0, 13).Value, Len(rng.Offset(0, 13).Value) - 4)
```

When I run the code I get a compile error to debug and it reads `Object Required`. What is it asking me to do?

This is a larger piece of the code:

```
strHSLtemp = "C:\Users\Desktop\To Do\MidDay Orders Macro Tool\Temp Files\HSL Orders Temp.xlsx"
wbHSLtemp = Dir(strHSLtemp)
Set wbHSLtemp = Workbooks.Open(strHSLtemp)
Set wsHSLtemp = wbHSLtemp.Sheets(1)
Dim arrModels() As String, strModel As String, blMultipleModels As Boolean, rngModel As range, lngModels As Long
Dim rng As range
Set strModel = Right(rng.Offset(0, 13).Value, Len(rng.Offset(0, 13).Value) - 4) 'strip off leading "HSL-"
strModel = Replace(strModel, " / ", "/") 'get rid of the spaces that appear to surround the forward slash
    If InStr(1, strModel, "/") > 0 Then 'yep, there are multiples
        blMultipleModels = True
    Else
        blMultipleModels = False
    End If
    If blMultipleModels = False Then 'just assign the model and move on in the outer loop
        wsHSLtemp.Cells(lastrowOutput, 12) = strModel
```

Comment: ```Set``` is used with variables which contain reference to objects. With values the ```Let``` can be used, but is optional and mostly ommited. So if you would like to be absolutely correct you can use ```Let strModel = "..."```.

Comment: A related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7724930/465053) as the root cause of the problem is same.

Answer (score 42):

You are trying to use the set keyword with a string variable. Set is only needed with Objects. Remove the set, and you should be fine:)

Specifically,
Change this:

```
Set strModel = Right(rng.Offset(0, 13).Value, Len(rng.Offset(0, 13).Value) - 4)
```

To This:

```
strModel = Right(rng.Offset(0, 13).Value, Len(rng.Offset(0, 13).Value) - 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you declared an `rng` variable, but you did not assign any value to it. So:

- Replace

  `Set strModel = Right(rng.Offset(0, 13).Value, Len(rng.Offset(0, 13).Value) - 4)`

  with

  `strModel = Right(rng.Offset(0, 13).Value, Len(rng.Offset(0, 13).Value) - 4) 'strip off leading "HSL-"`
- Assign a value to `rng` variable, some starting point for the offsets.